# Disabling the functions in a string c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I know that we can call functions with their name stored in a string like this:

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(TheCommandString);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

Is their any way in C# by which I can call all the functions in the class except the function in a string?

Want it in late binding, as I have array of strings which includes the methods name which needs to be discarded from the execution.

Comment: Use an `if/else`?

Comment: What do you mean `call all the functions in the class except`? You can get all method names and filter out the one you don't want. Are you asking how to get the names, how to call the methods or how to remove the unwanted strings?

Comment: You mean all of these methods? `this.GetType().GetMethods().Where(t => t.Name != "Whatever")`?

Comment: If there's a list of names you don't want you can use [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to remove the unwanted names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use reflection to execute all methods *except* a particular one, you just need to get all methods and exclude the one(s) you're not interested in. For example to exclude a single method name:

```
var methods = this.GetType().GetMethods()
    .Where(t => t.Name != "Whatever");

foreach(var method in methods)
{
    method.Invoke(this, userParameters);
}
```

If you have an list of method names, then you just need to change the filter, for example:

```
var methodNames = new [] { "Method1", "Method2" };

var methods = this.GetType().GetMethods()
    .Where(t => !methodNames.Contains(t.Name);
```